# SharePoint & IIS Anonymous Access

Tags: iis-7, sharepoint

Anonymous access is enabled in both central administration and on the site collection itself inside advanced permissions yet the site still is requiring a username and password. In IIS itself for the site both Windows Auth and Anonymous access are ticked. I would appriciate any suggestions on why the site is still requesting credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that any page content to be served up is published/checked in (images, master pages, styles, etc).

Beyond that as long as anonymous access is for sure enabled in the application settings in central admin there isn't a whole lot for you to do (in SharePoint).

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at this: [Enabling anonymous access in SharePoint 2007](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2006/09/25/Enabling-anonymous-access-in-SharePoint-2007.aspx) ?

Comment: Yea this is the site I used to learn how to enable anonymous access